# A single “upvote” action to a post in my feed requires 4 mongoDB queries. Can this be done better? Seems very inefficient

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, mongoose-schema

**High level**

I have a feed of posts that are all created by users. I want each post to have an “upvote” and a “downvote” button. Each user can only upvote/downvote a post once, or change their current vote (like Reddit).

**The problem**

I believe I have an “upvote/downvote” action flow that fits this criteria, except it takes 4 MongoDB queries to complete. I’m sure this is very inefficient, costly, and that there must be a better way.

**My current design**

These are my simplified Mongoose schemas:

1. **Users collection**.
2. **Posts collection** - this contains a reference ID field to the user that created the post.
3. **Votes collection** - this contains a reference ID field to the user that voted as well as an ID reference field to the post they voted on.

Every time the user votes on a post, “upvote” for example (passing us the post’s ID and their user ID), I query the **Votes collection** to see if there’s a match for both a reference post ID and user ID. This would mean the user already voted for this post.

Then there are 3 possible results after doing that:

1. Vote document exists and is same as sent vote: return an error (can’t do the same vote multiple times).
2. Vote document exists and is different as sent vote: update vote document from **Votes collection** with the new vote value (1 for upvote, -1 for downvote). Then, do a $inc query to add/subtract 1 or 2 to the matching posts ID’s post vote value. Then, after the atomic $inc operator finishes, taking that same post and doing a calculation based on current upvotes/downvotes to calculate a rank value (used to determine how high/low in the feed the post should be shown) - then setting the rank field of that post equal to the newly calculated rank (`foundPost.rank = calulatedresult`) and doing `foundPost.save();`
3. Vote document doesn’t exist in **Votes collection**: very similar to #2, just with creating documents instead of updating them…

This is a lot of queries just to do a few simple things! Is there any better way to do this? I feel like this is terrible coding, but it’s all I can figure out how to do from the docs. Help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following functionality to update the `votes` collection in a simpler update operation.

Assume that the `votes` collection document strcture is, for example:

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectId("62c59379ed72ad7e8e85a8d7"),
  user_id: 12,
  post_id: "Complex Update",
  vote_value: 1    // this can be 0, 1 (upvote) or -1 (downvote) values only.
}
```

**The update operation logic and function:**

If the *document not exists* ->

- create new document, with the three document fields (`vote_value` will be `1` or `-1`).

If the *document exists* ->

- if upvote && existing vote value == 1, already upvoted, send message "cannot upvote again". No update happens.
- if upvote && existing vote value == -1, update vote value to 0 (zero).
- if upvote && existing vote value == 0, update vote value to 1.
- if downvote && existing vote value == 1, update vote value to 0 (zero).
- if downvote && existing vote value == -1, already downvoted, send message "cannot downvote again". No update happens.
- if downvote && existing vote value == 0, update vote value to -1.

The input to the function are the three variables: `userid`, `postid` and the `votevalue` (values are `1` for upvote and `-1` for down vote). Note the update *creates new document* if the `post_id` and the`user_id` (together) do not exist in the collection (note the use of the `upsert` flag).

```
function updateVote(postid, userid, votevalue) {

  // Validate for input values...
  // Validate for votevalue == 1 or -1 
  // Convert votevalue to an integer, if required

  var result = db.test.findOneAndUpdate( 
    { post_id: postid, user_id: userid },
    [
        { 
            $set: { 
                vote_value: { $ifNull: [ "$vote_value", 0 ] } 
            } 
        },
        { 
            $set: { 
                vote_value: {
                    $switch: {
                        branches: [
                            { case: { $and: [ { $eq: [ votevalue, 1 ] }, { $eq: [ "$vote_value", -1 ] } ] }, then: 0 },
                            { case: { $and: [ { $eq: [ votevalue, 1 ] }, { $eq: [ "$vote_value", 0 ] } ] }, then: 1 },
                            { case: { $and: [ { $eq: [ votevalue, -1 ] }, { $eq: [ "$vote_value", 0 ] } ] }, then: -1 },
                            { case: { $and: [ { $eq: [ votevalue, -1 ] }, { $eq: [ "$vote_value", 1 ] } ] }, then: 0 },
                        ],
                        default: "$vote_value"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    ], 
    { 
        projection: { vote_value: 1 }, 
        upsert: true 
    }
  )

  if (result === null) {
      return "created new document";
  }

  if (votevalue === 1 && result.vote_value === 1) {
      return "cannot upvote again";
  }
  else if (votevalue === -1 && result.vote_value === -1) {
      return "cannot downvote again";
  }
  else {
      return "voted successfully";
  }

}
```

**NOTES:**

- The JavaScript function code is for the `mongosh` (or `mongo` shell).
- This requires MongoDB v4.2 or higher (uses Updates with Aggregation Pipeline).

Comment: NOTE: The logic doesn't include the calculation of the ranking.

Comment: This also doesn't include updating the resulting vote/score of the post.

Comment: Not to mention that this two-step approach is racy.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Collection's `findOneAndUpdate` method on a single document is an _atomic_ operation.

Comment: Ah, I retract the comment about race condition, my bad. The other point stands.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev _"This also doesn't include updating the resulting vote/score of the post."_. I have already NOTED about it in my first comment. Adding the update operation to Post collection doesn't need to change - it will be there as it is (I think, as per the available information). I also noted that you haven't made any useful comments / suggestions, yet to the questions raised in the Question.

Comment: "In MongoDB, update operations target a single collection. All write operations in MongoDB are atomic on the level of a single document." - from the documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/crud/#update-operations

Comment: @SergioTulentsev My answer to the Question post is about providing helpful suggestions and improvements for efficiency. Thats part of the request (_"This is a lot of queries just to do a few simple things! Is there any better way to do this?"_). ***Its a reasonable answer for issues posted***. If there is a correct and perfect answer, its possible someone will write it. Indeed there are better solutions if more time and effort is applied.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev From this StackOverflow link [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), there are two sub-topics of interest: (1) Answer a well asked question, (2) Write to the best of your ability.

Comment: What I meant to say is that your solution only eliminates one query out of the original four. While, undeniably, an improvement, the overall process is still quite complex. I guess the OP hoped for some more radical simplification. I'll let them to be the judge, though.

Comment: Me, I'd probably move this whole thing to redis. It has built-in data structures for ranking. And the whole operation with all steps can be done atomically.

Comment: _"What I meant to say is that your solution only eliminates one query out of the original four. "_ - Please explain. @SergioTulentsev

Comment: The original post contains workflow of four queries: 1) find on votes. 2) update on votes 3) $inc on posts (increment score) 4) update on posts (adjust ranking). Your solution combines 1 and 2 into one operation.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The `findOneAndUpdate` queries, creates / updates the votes collection in a single statement.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ... It is explained in plain text in the "Logic" part of the answer.

Comment: ... It also explains how an error message can be arrived at based on the query result - in case of the same vote is repeated. @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @SergioTulentsev _ _"...The other point stands."_ - What is your solution based upon the available information? Do you have an improvement / solution for the issue raised by yourself?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev _"Me, I'd probably move this whole thing to redis. ..."_ Thats your comment. Thats not an answer to the issues raised. Redis is not the platform the application is built on or being worked upon currently. Do you have a design, code, tests, and a plan to convert the existing MongoDB work to redis (and solve the whole issues)? Do you know how much time, resources and effort it takes for such an action?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev _"The original post contains workflow of four queries..."_ So, what is your solution / answer  (not comments) to make it efficient with the available information?

Comment: Thank you both for your work thus far. Your solution looks like a step in the right direction, however, it still seems inefficient. How do other companies deal with this situation (from a NoSQL perspective)? On top of your solution I still need to update the post then and rank. And Sergio, I was looking at Redis but I found MongoDB to be better for an overall primary DB for a social media app, what makes you say Redis?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The answer I wrote has some code that can be implemented or adapted. I believe its useful. It is not for somebody''s judgement. I dont know that Stack Overflow is a forum for  judging anything. ***Your comment: _" I'll let them to be the judge, though. "_.***

Comment: @MatthewTrent Why do you think your code is inefficient? It is difficult to understand without more details, like the code for the queries, how much data, the data structure / model. Can you tell in what terms the code is inefficient? Which part of the code or queries are inefficient and in what way?

Comment: @prasad_ Correct me if I’m wrong as you know more than I, but I try to keep all my actions (creating a post, updating user info, logging in, creating account, etc.) to as few queries as possible. To me, this means they will be fast, and not cost too much (30mil reads = $0.30). However, if a single “like” action is 3 queries (with it being a very common action; I expect users to do it a ton), won’t this add up to a really high cost?

Comment: @MatthewTrent I wasn't suggesting to use redis as the primary db, just to move the ranking / voting to it. You can still use mongodb for the rest and even persist ranking data in it for extra safety. "what makes you say redis" - in the past, I've built a thing you describe using redis and I liked how it turned out.